# Is there any way that I can store all the recieved messages at MQTT client side?

Tags: mqtt

I was running Mosquitto broker on my PC.

I opened two command prompt windows in the same PC. From the first  window, I published the message "First_Message" with the topic name 'Hello' using this command.

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t Hello -m "First_Message"
```

From another command window, subscribed to the same topic using:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t Hello
```

Then I was able to see the "First_Message" received and printed in command window.

Now, what exactly I need is rather than printing this message in that command window, is there any way that I can store this received message in a text file on the same PC.

Comment: You can do what ever you want client side, it's your code. Update the question with what client you are using in what language and share the code you have tried already

Comment: Thanks for your response, As I already mentioned I was running Mosquitto as MQTT broker on my PC and I opened two command prompt windows and then from one window, I published the message like "Hello" with the topic named 'message' and in another window I subscribed to the same topic. And I was able to see the recieved message in command prompt, but I want to store the message in any text file?

Comment: You still haven't explained which client you are using (I can guess, but that's not the point) EDIT the question to include the exact details of what you are doing. Do not answer with a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe the output to a file using normal shell conventions.

```
moquitto_sub -t Hello > log_file.txt
```

If you want to have the topic name prefixed to the payload use the `-v` command line argument. There should be no need to use the `-d` option

```
moquitto_sub -v -t Hello > log_file.txt
```